# Using #ifdefs for code selection creates ugly constructs - alternatives?

Tags: c++, optimization, preprocessor

Currently my code looks approximately like

```
#ifdef A
#include "include_a.h"
#endif

#ifdef B
#include "include_b.h"
#endif

void func_A()
{
#ifdef A
    do_stuff_a();
#endif
}

void func_B()
{
#ifdef B
    do_stuff_b();
#else
    do_other_stuff();
#endif
}

void func_C()
{
    do_stuff_c();
}
int main(void)
{
#ifdef A
#ifdef B
    do_AB_stuff();
#else
    do_A_stuff();
#endif
func_A();
func_B();
func_C();
return 0;
}
```

The reason for that is: I am using cmake for linking additional libraries/headers. If those headers/libraries are linked, it makes sense to call the included functions, if not, compilation will fail. That allows me to run the program both with and without additional libraries (for example, if I just want to test `func_C()`, without having the computational overload of `func_B()` and `func_A()`, or if library A and B are not available on the system).
Still, that makes rather ugly code, with quite a lot of `#ifdefs` around. Thus, is there a way to get the same functionality (preferably being controllable by a cmake-script), but without having to use all those `#ifdefs`?

Comment: Depending on what `A` and `B` represents, you could perhaps us different source files to be built conditionally by CMake?

Comment: You might try using `#if`.   `#if defined(A) && defined(B)` can test if both `A` and `B` are defined.   `#if defined(A) && !defined(B)` can test if `A` is defined and `B` is not.    Also consider using `#elif`  (e.g. `#elif defined(B) && !defined(A)`).   These things allow testing multiple conditions in one line, rather than across several, as can happen if you only use `#ifdef` and `#else`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how big libraries A and B are, you may be able to write stub libraries, with functions that do nothing or return hard-coded values or whatever makes sense. Then you can link with either the real library or your stub library for testing `func_C()`

As an example, if the real library's API is just

```
include_a.h:

void do_stuff_a();
void do_A_stuff();
```

Your stubs might be:

```
stub_a.cpp:

void do_stuff_a() {}
void do_A_stuff() {}
```

Then you can get rid of all the `#ifdef A` and just link with the stub file if not using the library.

Comment: Still I have to remove quite a lot of code from the main program (as seen in `func_B()` and `func_A()`, thus just omitting the linking of the libraries would not help much...

Comment: @arc_lupus No. You would write a library which has functions `do_stuff_a()` and `do_A_stuff()`, but which actually does nothing (empty functions). Then you would link with either the real library or your stub library. If you are only interested in checking functionality C, it won't matter that A and B are doing nothing

Comment: If I would like to do that, but for class functions (i.e. func_A(), func_B() and func_C() are now members of a class), how would I solve it in that case?

Comment: @arc_lupus It would be the exact same thing. Whatever the API of library A is (i.e. whatever is in `include_a.h`), you would implement the same API for your stub library.

Comment: Which means: 1. Put the class declaration into the header of the library. 2. Put the class functions into the cpp-file of the library, with one file with stubs and one with real functions. 3. Create different cmake-paths for stubs and functions. 4. Success?

Comment: @arc_lupus yes, but #1 and half of #2 should already be the case. no need to do anything there, just create the stubs file.

Comment: I ran into another problem: Some of the functions are templated functions, which can not be moved into cpp-files...

Comment: @arc_lupus Then you already have those functions and don't need to reimplement them as stubs. Only implement stubs for whatever is implemented in the library itself (the *.a or *.so or *.lib or *.dll file).

Comment: Yes, but that means that I have to keep the #ifdef-mess in those functions?

Comment: @arc_lupus No. why would you?

Answer (score 0):

You can create what is known as a stub library/implementation, and then decide whether to link to that library or the one which have the real implementation.

File `a_stub.c`:

```
#include "include_a.h"

void func_A() {} // Does nothing. Returns a placeholder value if necessary.
```

File `a_real.c`:

```
#include "include_a.h"

void func_A() { do_stuff_a(); }
```

Same for B and C. Then you pick `*_real.c` or `*_stub.c` depending on your interest (namely, the cases where you define `A`, `B`, and `C` macros).

Edit: This is probably what @Baruch commented in another answer. I saw his comment after posting the answer.